plugin commonjs--resolver SyntaxError: Unexpected token Vue3 (upgrade) + rollup
//Package.json below for the project
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
        "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
        "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^25.0.7",
        "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^13.0.0",
        "@rollup/plugin-replace": "^5.0.5",
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0-beta.9",
        "eslint": "^8.0.0",
        "eslint-config-standard": "^17.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
        "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.0.0",
        "jest": "^27.0.0",
        "rollup": "^2.8.0",
        "rollup-plugin-vue": "^6.0.0",
        "vue3-jest": "^27.0.0-alpha.1",
        "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
        "vue-sfc-rollup": "^4.1.2"
    }
}

//rollup.config.js for the project
import vue from 'rollup-plugin-vue';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
export default {
    plugins: [
        resolve(),
        replace(
          {
            preventAssignment: true,
            changed: 'replaced',
            delimiters: ['', '']
          }
        ),
        commonjs({exclude: 'src/**',}),
        vue(),
        terser()
    ]
};

I'm upgrading the entier project to Vue3 and getting this error:
 [!] (plugin commonjs--resolver) SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:4) in /webapp/static/js/vue/pages/blah.vue?vue&type=template&id=8bc0d530&lang.js
the code works fine for vue2. Did someone solve this?

If all of your packages are ESM you could probably skip that package with latest Vite.
